# using TSIG how to add zone named configuration file?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

Ive set up 2 dns servers. using tsig can someone tell me or direct me to a how to for adding zone to named.conf or named.conf.local file automatically? i mean if i add a zone in named.conf and file of the zone, i want it to be executed in the second server auto. is there a howto? tutorial? any one can direct me or?

bind9-debian

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly with TSIG, but yes - `rndc addzone`.

http://jpmens.net/2010/10/04/dynamically-add-zones-to-bind-with-rndc-addzone/

On the master you add master zone, on the slave - slave zone.

But you will need to create a master zone file first (can be generic template which can fit for any zone). Either you create the file in the real-time (maybe with scp or something), or you create a bunch of "empty" zone files beforehand and use them in `rndc` command.